# Elasticsearch aggregation of deep nested type

Tags: json, elasticsearch, aggregate

Previously I have asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841542/elasticsearch-metric-aggregation-number-of-elements-in-array/31846457?noredirect=1#comment51642542_31846457) question.

The example document there was a simplified document. That was good for me to understand the differences in aggregation over non-nested type versus nested type. However, the simplification was hiding further complexity and so I have to expand on the question here.

So my actual documents are closer to the following:

```
"_source": {
    "keyword": "my keyword",
    "response": [
        {
            "results": [
                {
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "prop": [
                                {
                                    "item_property_1": ["A"],
                                }
                            ]
                            ( ... other properties )
                        },
                        {
                            "prop": [
                                {
                                    "item_property_1": ["B"],
                                }
                            ]
                            ( ... other properties )
                        },
                        ( ... other items )
                    ]
                }
            ],
            ( ... other properties )
        }
    ]
}
```

So I kept the crucial properties `keyword`, `items`, and `item_property_1`, but hid lots of other things that complicate the situation. First, notice that compared to the referenced question there is lots of extra nesting: between the root and "items", and between "items" and "item_property_1". Additionally, notice also that the properties `response` and `results` are both arrays with a single element. It's weird, but that's how it is :-)

Now, the reason why this question is different from the one cited above is that I tried the accepted answer (which does work for the example there), and it doesn't work here. That is, if I use a mapping with:

```
"items": {
    "type":"nested",
    "properties": {
        "prop": {
            "properties": {
                "item_property_1": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then the aggregation doesn't work. It returns zero hits.

I will edit later and provider a ready to use sample bulk insert.

EDIT:
Alright, below I show three queries which are respectively: mapping, bulk insert and aggregation (with zero hits)

Mapping (with `"type":"nested"` as indicated in the previous answered question)

```
PUT /test2/_mapping/test3
{
    "test3": {
        "properties": {
            "keyword": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "response": {
                "properties": {
                    "results": {
                        "properties": {
                            "items": {
                                "type": "nested",
                                "properties": {
                                    "prop": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "item_property_1": {
                                                "type": "string",
                                                "index": "not_analyzed"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Bulk put:

```
PUT /test2/test3/_bulk
{ "index": {}}
{    "keyword": "my keyword",    "response": [        {            "results": [                {                    "items": [                        {                            "prop": [                                {"item_property_1": ["A"]}                            ]                        },                        {                            "prop": [                                {"item_property_1": ["B"]}                            ]                        },                        {                            "prop": [                                {"item_property_1": ["A"]}                            ]                        }                    ]                }            ]        }    ]}
{ "index": {}}
{    "keyword": "different keyword",    "response": [        {            "results": [                {                    "items": [                        {                            "prop": [                                {"item_property_1": ["A"]}                            ]                        },                        {                            "prop": [                                {"item_property_1": ["C"]}                            ]                        }                    ]                }            ]        }    ]}
```

Aggregation (zero hits):

```
POST /test2/test3/_search
{
    "size":0,
    "aggregations": {
        "item_property_1_count": {
            "terms":{
                "field":"item_property_1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really different from the previous answer. All you need is to modify the field names a little bit to take into account the additional nesting. Other than that, nothing needs to change in the mapping. Note that this query works without mapping changes only because `response` and `results` are both arrays with a single element, if it wasn't the case, it would be more involved and would require mapping changes and a different query.

The query now looks like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "by_keyword": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "prop_1_count": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "response.results.items"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "prop_1": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "response.results.items.prop.item_property_1"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the results:

```
{
  ...
  "aggregations" : {
    "by_keyword" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key" : "different keyword",
        "doc_count" : 1,
        "prop_1_count" : {
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "prop_1" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [ {
              "key" : "A",
              "doc_count" : 1
            }, {
              "key" : "C",
              "doc_count" : 1
            } ]
          }
        }
      }, {
        "key" : "my keyword",
        "doc_count" : 1,
        "prop_1_count" : {
          "doc_count" : 3,
          "prop_1" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [ {
              "key" : "A",
              "doc_count" : 2
            }, {
              "key" : "B",
              "doc_count" : 1
            } ]
          }
        }
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're correct again. Clearly I still haven't been able to wrap my mind around these queries yet. Thanks again :-)

Comment: what I want aggregation for another field her like :response.results.items.prop.item_property_2 so how I can use it in the query?

Comment: @SurajDalvi please create a new question.